# Sessions Api, undefined method downcase

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, session, authentication

I've started to create an Api for my rails application. I am currently creating the Sessions Controller for Log in.

But for some reason I am getting this error

```
NoMethodError
in Api::V1::SessionsController#create

undefined method `downcase&#x27; for nil:NilClass;
```

I am not understanding why this is happening. I am also using the downcase method in my traditional sessions controller and I don't have this problem.

**API CONTROLLER**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                       :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

      respond_to :json

      def create 
        user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
          sign_in user
        end
        render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged In Successfully",
                      :data => {  } }
      end

    end
  end
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase) ###THIS WORKS FINE
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to publishers_path
    end
  end

end
```

**ROUTES**

```
# API Routes

namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

Comment: Check if you have any funky whitespaces after downcase.

Comment: yea i don't, its really odd...

Comment: Oh, well your edit was much needed.  `params[:session][:email]` is nil so that's why your downcase is failing.   Since it's an API you should really be checking to make sure people are passing you all the valid data you need to successfully make the call.

Comment: any idea why the above command may be entering a nil email?

Comment: It's not entering a nil email.  But your email isn't stored in `params[:session][:email]`.  Try `params[:user][:email]`

Comment: crap i totally missed that. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your checking `params[:session][:email]`

but with the curl call:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST localhost:3000/api/sessions -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"secret@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"secret\"}}"
```

The email will still be stored in `params[:user][:email]`

Also, you should check that the user passed that argument to you're api, because you have noticed that it will fail without it.

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email].downcase) if defined? params[:user][:email]
```

Comment: Would this solution change my Routes to :users?

Comment: No, your routing configuration (How your app reacts to `POST localhost:3000/api/sessions`) is different than what your controller does with your parameters (How your app reacts to `"{\"user\":{\"email\":\"secret@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"secret\"}}"`)